# Manual Positioning of Shareaholic ShareBar Plugin

Tags: css-position

I'm trying to manually position the Shareaholic sharebar WP plugin. I am using a vertical one, and want it to be in a fixed position on the left side of my screen beside my main content area. So far I have figured out how to get it onto my site, but not able to position it. I'm referencing [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/vertical-sharing-bar?replies=7) of someone who tried to do a similar thing.

I'm using this code to insert it into my single.php

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[shareaholic app="share_buttons" id="4766761"]'); ?>
```

But haven't had any luck with getting css positioning to work, or where exactly to put it in my single.php file

Right now it's just below this code :

```
<main class='content units <?php avia_layout_class( 'content' ); ?>' <?php avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'content','post_type'=>'post'));?>>
```

And it's showing up above the post content.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Jonny

Answer (score 2):

Custom CSS should be added to your styles.css theme file, but it is recommended to [create a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme) when making any adjustments within your theme so that you will not run the risk of losing your customization if/when your theme releases a new version and you update.